# Pages - how to hide header but not footer on first page of section?

Tags: pages, text

In Pages, there is an option to hide headers and footers on the first page of a section.

But I want to *only* hide the header, not the footer. That's because I have the page number in the footer and I *do* want to show it, even on the first page. How can I do this?

At first I thought I could just put the first page into a separate section, but that breaks up paragraphs that flow from the first page onto the second.

If this is not possible with Pages, do you know of another word processor that can do this?

EDIT: Here's an overview of the problem situation:

[image: problem situation]

Comment: Set up that page, take picture then show that pic...

Comment: I added a screenshot of the problem situation in the original post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to Ask Different!

Sorry that I don't know the proper solution to your problem through Pages or any other word processor. If you can not find such a solution and still want to do this, you would maybe like to consider doing something similar through a text box in Pages as follows:

1. Hide the Headers & Footers on the first page again,
2. Place a text box via **Insert > Text Box** menu option and write 1 in it. You can resize the text box by click-and-holding and then dragging one of the selection handles in its edges with a mouse,
3. Place the text box at the same location where the page number would reside in the first page,
4. Format the text box by selecting the **None** option in the **Arrange > Stay on Page > Text Wrap** dropbox menu on the sidebar after clicking on the **Format** button in the Pages toolbar at the top right. This will make sure the text box remains in the first page and at the same location in the first page even if you add more content to your document,
5. You can fine-tune the box's location by selecting it and then changing the numbers in  the **Position X-Y** options in the **Format > Arrange** tab on the sidebar again.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Only an alternate solution: LaTeX + Emacs(editor) + Org-mode(package inside Emacs). An example in the picture below:

[image]

Please note the Contents can be removed if needed. Footer and page numbering is separate in LaTeX.